# How to download a file from GitHub as html instead of txt?

Tags: github

Using the "raw" option and "save as" in Github I get the file download in txt format, but want it in HTML. How do you get it to download to HTML format?

Comment: HTML is a text format. Is the file you are trying to download html? It's not clear what the issue is here.

Comment: Do you mean you want the Content type as text/html instead of text/plain? Otherwise just save the file as .html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The original file uploaded was HTML but it kept saving as txt, and I realized the solution was as simple as adding ".html" at the end of the file name when I saved it to my computer. Thanks to everyone who responded however!